# How to convert an object instance to shared_ptr instance

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Suppose I had two shared_ptr types such as

```
boost::shared_ptr<ObjA> sptrA;
boost::shared_ptr<ObjB> sptrB;
```

Now suppose that `sptrA->SomeMethod()` returned a simple ObjB type (not a shared ptr). Is it possible for me to store that type somehow in sptrB ? So that I could do something like this so that the returned type instance is automatically converted to boost_shared ptr

```
sptrB = sptrA->SomeMethod();
```

I asked this question just of curiosity and whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: What exactly does `SomeMethod` return? A reference? A copy? A pointer? And how is that reference/copy/pointer created?

Comment: It returns a value type (A Copy).

Comment: `sptrB = boost::make_shared<ObjType>(sptrA->SomeMethod());` is an obvious answer, but that is not what you are looking for, right? Too complicated?

Comment: @jogojapan that solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most standard way of creating `boost:shared_ptr` objects is to use the `make_shared` function provided by Boost:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

struct A {};

A generator() {
  return A();
}

int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  shared_ptr<A> p = make_shared<A>(generator());
  return 0;
}
```

Since the `generator()` function returns an `A` object by value, the syntax above implies that `new` is invoked with the copy contructor of `A`, and the resulting pointer is wrapped in a shared-pointer object. In other words, `make_shared` doesn't quite perform a *conversion* to shared pointer; instead, it creates a copy of the object on the heap and provides memory management for that. This may or may not be what you need.

---

Note that this is equivalent to what `std::make_shared` does for `std::shared_ptr` in C++11.

---

One way to provide the convenient syntax you mentioned in your question is to define a conversion operator to `shared_ptr<A>` for `A`:

```
struct A {
  operator boost::shared_ptr<A>() {
    return boost::make_shared<A>(*this);
  }
};
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
shared_ptr<A> p = generate();
```

This will automatically "convert" the object returned by the function. Again, *conversion* here really means heap allocation, copying and wrapping in a shared pointer. Therefore, I am not really sure if I'd recommend defining such a convenience conversion operator. It makes the syntax very convenient, but it, as all implicit conversion operators, may also mean that you implicitly cause these "conversions" to happen in places you didn't expect.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ 11 you can use `std::make_shared<T>()` function [(link)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Example:

```
int a = 10;
std::shared_ptr<int> shared_a = std::make_shared<int>(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on precisely what `ObjA::SomeMethod` returns - a copy, a reference or a pointer. In the first two cases it would not be feasible to wrap it into a `shared_ptr` (because `shared_ptr` needs a *pointer*).

The third case is possible, but you must proceed with caution. Make sure that once you wrap a pointer to an object into a `shared_ptr`, no one else attempts to manage the lifetime of that object.

For example, if you return a raw pointer, wrap it into a shared pointer and then, at some point later in the program, someone `delete`s that same pointer, you will have a problem.